# Value of type 'Cursor' cannot be converted to 'Short'

Tags: vb.net

I have migrated VB6 to dot net and I am getting:

> Value of type 'Cursor' cannot be converted to 'Short'

Here is my code:

```
Dim intSavePointer As Short ' Save off the MousePointer

' Change the mouse pointer to clue in user of update

intSavePointer = **MyBase.Cursor**(this is the error line of code)

' Change the mouse pointer back

 **MyBase.Cursor** = intSavePointer
```

How to fix that?

Comment: In .NET, I'd recommend to wrap this in a `Try` / `Finally` to ensure that the cursor gets set back even if you have an unexpected exit from the routine (e.g. an exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Dim intSavePointer As Short` to `Dim savedCursor As Cursor`.

A `Cursor` is not an `int`.  I don't know why it ever worked in VB6, but I've never used that.

Comment: @nanehero Or alternatively use `Dim savedCursor = MyBase.Cursor` with `Option Infer On`, then you don't need to know exactly what the type is, and VB will infer it from the expression.