# Value of type 'Cursor' cannot be converted to enumerator

Tags: vb.net

I migrated code from Vb6 to Vb.Net and I am getting "Value of type 'Cursor' cannot be converted to enumerator" error. The code is below

```
Public Property MousePointer() As enmMousePointer
    Get
        MousePointer = MyBase.Cursor(this where error been thrown)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As enmMousePointer)

        MyBase.Cursor = Value
        RaiseEvent MousePointerChange()
    End Set
End Property
```

the below one is the enmMousePointer

```
Public Enum enmMousePointer

    Default_Renamed = 0
    Arrow = 1
    Cross = 2
    I_beam = 3
    Icon = 4
    Size = 5
    Size_NE_SW = 6
    Size_N_S = 7
End Enum
```

Comment: If your property is type `enmMousePointer` then it needs to return a value of that type, not

Comment: This is the [same problem as last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315155/value-of-type-cursor-cannot-be-converted-to-short).. change it to: Public Property MousePointer() As Cursor    I don't see why you would need an enum since the cursors are [all here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursors?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: What you do is up to you but I have to say that it is just plain silly to use an "enum" prefix on `Enum` types.  Hungarian notation is bad enough as it is but it was never meant to be used like that.  There are loads of enumerations in the .NET Framework and not a one of those has a prefix like that and everyone seems to be able to use them just fine.  Why should yours be any different?  It may be that you have a teacher who is stuck in VB6-land from two decades ago and you're just doing what they have shown you.  Stop as soon as you can.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney.. now you are my guru :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your property is type `enmMousePointer` then it needs to return a value of that type, not a `Cursor` object.  I'm not sure why that's not obvious.  As far as I can tell, you need to use a series of `If` statements to test the current value of the `Cursor` property and return the corresponding `enmMousePointer` value, e.g.

```
If Cursor Is Cursors.Arrow Then
    Return enmMousePointer.Arrow
```